# How to get data from the live table using web scraping?

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to set up a live table by downloading the data directly from a website through Python. I guess I am following all the steps to the dot but I still am not able to get the data from the said table.

I have referred to many web pages and blogs to try to correct the issue here but was unsuccessful. I would like the stack overflow community's help here.

The following is the table website and there is only one table on the page from which I am trying to get the data:

https://etfdb.com/themes/smart-beta-etfs/#complete-list__esg&sort_name=assets_under_management&sort_order=desc&page=1

The data on the table is partially available for free and the rest is paid. So I guess that is the problem here but I would assume I should be able to download the free data. But since this is my first time trying this and considering I am a beginner at Python, I can be wrong. So please all the help is appreciated.

The code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

import html5lib

import lxml

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests


site = 'https://etfdb.com/themes/smart-beta-etfs/#complete-list&sort_name=assets_under_management&sort_order=desc&page=1'

page1 = requests.get(site, proxies = proxy_support)

page1

page1.status_code

page1.text

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(page1.text, 'html.parser')

print(soup)

print(soup.prettify())

table = soup.find_all("div", class_ = "fixed-table-body")

table
```

When I run the table command, it gives me no data and the field is completely empty even though there is a table available on the website. All the help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page does an another request for this info which returns json you can parse

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://etfdb.com/data_set/?tm=77630&cond=&no_null_sort=&count_by_id=&sort=assets_under_management&order=desc&limit=25&offset=0').json()
```

Some of the keys (those for output columns Symbol and ETF Name - keys `symbol` and `name`) are associated with html so you can use bs4 to handle those values and extract the final desired result; the other keys value pairs are straightforward.

For example, if you loop each row in the json

```
for row in r['rows']:
    print(row)
    break
```

You get rows for parsing, of which two items need bs4 like [this](https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=ac1c7b0b38ea46dcb3f3f99bc6091153).

---

Python:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd

r = requests.get('https://etfdb.com/data_set/?tm=77630&cond=&no_null_sort=&count_by_id=&sort=assets_under_management&order=desc&limit=25&offset=0').json()
results = []

for row in r['rows']:
    soup = bs(row['symbol'], 'lxml')
    symbol = soup.select_one('.caps').text
    soup = bs(row['name'], 'lxml')
    etf_name = soup.select_one('a').text
    esg_score = row['esg_quality_score']
    esg_quality_score_pctl_peer = row['esg_quality_score_pctl_peer']
    esg_quality_score_pctl_global = row['esg_quality_score_pctl_global']
    esg_weighted_avg_carbon_inten = row['esg_weighted_avg_carbon_inten']
    esg_sustainable_impact_pct = row['esg_sustainable_impact_pct']
    row = [symbol, etf_name, esg_score, esg_quality_score_pctl_peer , esg_quality_score_pctl_global, esg_weighted_avg_carbon_inten, esg_sustainable_impact_pct ]
    results.append(row)

headers = ['Symbol', 'ETF Name', 'ESG Score', 'ESG Score Peer Percentile (%)', 'ESG Score Global Percentile (%)',
           'Carbon Intensity (Tons of CO2e / $M Sales)', 'Sustainable Impact Solutions (%)']

df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns = headers)
print(df)
```

Comment: Thank you. This seems to work. I will just need to parse the data and clean it.

Comment: I updated for you now I have more time to give dataframe. Note there is more info in the json than on the page.

Comment: Thank you very much. I just had another doubt. How did you find this particular URL? Since the URL I shared is different from the one you have used

Comment: I found it in the network tab via dev tools (F12) when loading your webpage.

Comment: Im sorry but I am new to stack overflow. What do you mean by 'accepting an answer'?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to use `pandas` data frame to fetch the table and can export the into csv.

```
import pandas as pd

tables=pd.read_html("https://etfdb.com/themes/smart-beta-etfs/#complete-list&sort_name=assets_under_management&sort_order=desc&page=1")
table=tables[0][:-1]
print(table)
table.to_csv('table.csv') #You can find the csv file in project folder after run
```